# How well does freshly baked sandwich bread fly?

Tags: storage-lifetime

I'm going on vacation soon and wanted to take homemade bread with me, but I'm unsure as to how the bread would last through the long plane flight. How does bread usually fare when flying?

Comment: About the same time it fares not flying.

Comment: @paparazzo  I agree. Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: I'd check with the airport and airline if you can bring bread .

Comment: There will be a very minor influence, see the Hafely-Keating experiment :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

About the same time it fares not flying.  Flying is not something the bread is aware of.

Comment: Good point. Also, that made me smile. Thanks for brightening my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Would add, the bread should be completely cool before wrapping it in foil and cling wrap. Otherwise you will find yourself with soggy bread upon disembarking! Should this happen, stick it in the oven (uncut) at 275 for 20 minutes or so to help dry it out again

Answer (score -3):

After it is completely cool, wrap it tighly in aluminum foil then wrap tightly in cling wrap. Place in a ziploc baggie and freeze.
If the recipe contains no oil, other fat and/or no sugar, the answer is 'not very well'.
Real French bread will go stale in 24 hours or less